# Pass dynamic data in angular2 route. If possible or not?

Tags: angular

I have to pass data with routing in angular2. But, our requirement this data is dynamic. If possible or not in angular2 ?

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'heroes', component : HeroDetailComponent, data : {some_data : variable_dyanamic_data}}
];
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use `:` to pass dynamic data**

```
   const routes: RouterConfig = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
      {path : 'heroes/:some_data', component : HeroDetailComponent}
    ];
```

Edit : - To know more [Read this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)

Comment: I Have to pass data not a url params. Route params & data also different in angular2

Comment: if you dont have to pass data as url param then why do you want to use route. just use a global service to store data when u are on 1 st page then use the same service to extract the data when you are in 2nd page (after routing) this is reason for using single page application as your page dont get refreshed so is you js files so you can store and extract data from them at any point